# Unexpected end of stream, on my friends pc but not mine. .Net Core, SQL

Tags: .net, sql-server, browser, .net-core, runtime-error

As the title says my friend gets this error on a website I've made.
When he tried to add a Car to the database.

The error:
[image]

He sent me this picture.

The car has theese props:

```
 public class CarModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Årsmodel")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Märke")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Modell")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Hästkrafter")]
    public int HorsePower { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Färg")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fyrhjulsdrift")]
    public bool IsFourWheelDrive { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Pris")]
    [Range(0,int.MaxValue)]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Övrigt/Beskrivning")]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Miltal")]
    public int Miles { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Bränsle")]
    public string Fuel { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Automatlåda")]
    public bool IsAutomatic { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Bilder")]
    public List<PicturePathModel> Pictures { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Är bilen påväg?")]
    public bool IsOnTheWay { get; set; }
}
```

The PicutePathModel is just a model with a path to the Images.

The form that is filled out has 12 inputs(strings, ints and bools)
and one file selector.

My guess is that the error comes from the file selector.

Why do he get theese errors and not me? Is it because hes pc is older?
That hes browser doesn't support the file selector?

Here is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCar(CreateCarVM VM)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var CarToSave =  VM.Car;
        if (VM.Images != null)
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var listOfPaths = new List<PicturePathModel>();
            var randomName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var SaveFileIn = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "images", randomName);
            var pathToSaveFileIn = "/images/"+randomName;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveFileIn);
            foreach (var file in VM.Images)
            {
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var path = new PicturePathModel()
                    {
                        Path = Path.Combine(pathToSaveFileIn, file.FileName)
                    };
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(SaveFileIn, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                    path.CarModelId = VM.Car.Id;
                    Console.WriteLine(pathToSaveFileIn);
                    listOfPaths.Add(path);
                    _context.Pictures.Add(path);
                }
            }
            CarToSave.Pictures = listOfPaths;
        }                     
        //Save the car.
        _context.CarModels.Add(CarToSave);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return View(VM);
    }
```

What can the problem be?
Really grateful for every answer.

Comment: Can it be that multifile picker doesn't support old broswers?

Comment: Hello anyone? :P

Answer (score 0):

It shows that hes web browser was really old.

So if anyone gets this error and are using the multi attribute. Check the browser version.